# Send input file with other strings in PHP error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send input file and some strings via ajax, but I can't send the file because it doesn't have to be processed ( so i should use processData: false) but if I use it every string I pass result as not indexed

JS script:

```
var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var Surname = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
    var Residence = document.getElementById("Residence").value;
    var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    var Phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
    var JCurriculum = document.getElementById("Curriculum").files[0];
    var Curriculum = new FormData();
    Curriculum.append("Curriculum", JCurriculum);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "scripts/register.php",
        data: {
            Name: Name,
            Surname: Surname,
            Residence: Residence,
            Email: Email,
            Phone: Phone,
            Curriculum: Curriculum
        },            
        success: function (Curriculum) {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
```

PHP script:

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Residence = $_POST['Residence'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$Curriculum = $_POST['Curriculum'];

$Name = filter_var($Name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Surname = filter_var($Surname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$Residence = filter_var($Residence, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);;
$Phone = filter_var($Phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);;
```

If I put `processData:false` in the before `success:` I have this error `Undefined index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're sending is incorrect. Instead of serialising a FormData object along with form-urlencoded data, you need to `append()` all information (input values and files) in to the FormData object and then send that only.

You will also need to set both `contentType` and `processData` properties to `false`. Try this:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Name', $('#Name').val());
formData.append('Surname', $('#Surname').val());
formData.append('Residence', $('#Residence').val());
formData.append('Email', $('#Email').val());
formData.append('Phone', $('#Phone').val());
formData.append('Curriculum', $('#Curriculum')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "scripts/register.php",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(Curriculum) {
    alert('Success');
  }
});
```

Also note that if all the information you want to send in the request is contained within a single `<form />` element then you can simplify the FormData creation by providing the reference to the form element to the object constructor:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#yourForm')[0]);
```

Comment: The error no longer occurs, but in the email I receive I don't see anything attached. My PHP: $Curriculum = $_POST['Curriculum']; $mail->Body     = "<h1>Contact from Website</h1>
<ul>
<li>Nome: {$Name}</li>
<li>Cognome: {$Surname}</li>
<li>Comune di residenza: {$Residence}</li>
<li>Email: {$Email}</li>
<li>Telefono: {$Phone}</li>
<li>Curriculum: {$Curriculum}</li>
</ul>"; There is more code but i show the most important, i can see all the strings like email , name ecc... but I don't receive the curriculum attached

Comment: Curriculum is binary data, so you need to use `$_FILES` to retrieve it. I'd strongly suggest you read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: Thank you a lot, I checked it as solved , you're the best . Only 1 thing ... when i upload .txt or .png i can see the file received via Email , but if I upload a .pdf It doesn't send the email $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['Curriculum']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['Curriculum']['name']);

Comment: Glad you got it working. That's very odd behaviour. The file type shouldn't make any difference. I'd suggest starting a new question about that